# Why does my load balancer add the header "Via 1.1 localhost.localdomain"

Tags: load-balancing, http, rackspace-cloud

My load balancer (a Rackspace Cloud Load Balancer instance) adds the [Via header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.45) with these values:

```
Via 1.1 localhost.localdomain
```

What does this mean and is it harmful?

Note: According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435477/why-is-googles-home-page-logo-served-with-contradictory-expires-and-cache-co) Google also serves this in production.

Answer (score 1):

Load balancers are effectively proxies, so they pass the "Via" header along so your web server can record it for statistics. Otherwise, all traffic would be appearing from the load balancer instead of individual clients.

The "localhost.localdomain" should be configurable in the balancer itself.

Comment: Thanks. What business value do I get in configuring this "localhost.localdomain" name?

Comment: I should have asked before - where did you do the test from? If I remember correctly, the Via header is supposed to have the IP address of the client.

Comment: Two different windows PCs